# Word meaning notes about a document

Tags: terminology, obscure-terms

Is there a word with a meaning like "about this document" or "notes about a document"?

That is a section of a document which contains meta information about the document, such as its purpose, intended audience, editorial history, origins, and so on.

Comment: While it's not a word with the specific meaning you mention, I'm pretty sure most of this stuff usually just goes in a section entitled "Introduction" or "Preface."  If the material is broader in scope and not intended to all be read before the document, I've seen books (for example) with a section entitled simply, "About This Book."  No reason not to have a section called "About This Document" or "Notes [on This Document]" or whatever.

Comment: On a website, the word used for a link where the web designers would put that information is "about."  There would simply be a word "About" appearing underlined as a hotlink that you would, if interested, then click on to access such information.  If included as part of the text of a book, rather than, say, on the book jacket, it would appear in a section called the "appendix." How you would title the information within the appendix would depend on what it was, like how the book came about might have the word "background" in the title or be simply "Background."

Comment: Meta - [meta.se]

Comment: Thanks for these responses. I was curious whether there was a specific word for this, the way - for example - "errata" means "errors in this document", but I will continue to use the generic "About this document".